# Regression model that predicts the changes in the category of dependent variables?

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling

I have some dependent variables that an event might changes their categories. Assume I have the following dataset

```
  Students   Category 
    A          Poor
    B          Good 
    C          Excellent
```

I have an event (as my predictor variables) in a binary format ( $1$ indicates that they are exposed to the event and $0$ otherwise) and I wish to measure the effect of events on the **changes of category**. So, after events we will have the following scenario:

```
  Students    Event   Category
    A           0       Poor 
    B           1       Good
    C           1       Good
```

What is the appropriate regression model in this scenario? I know about **Ordinal Logistic Regression** that somehow can be used by transforming the data but does anyone has other suggestions?

Comment: Do you have information about the variable in your data both before and after the event? Or are these separate data sets that can't be merged? And how many response categories (poor, good, excellent, etc.) do you have in your variable (*Category*)?

Comment: Hi Tahir, yes, we a have all the information before and after events. All the ids ( I in this example, students) have a unique identifier and two data set can be merge together. In total we have 9 response categories.

Comment: Hi, it might sound rather careless and I understand there is a categorical variable, but if response categories are ordered, what about assigning them numbers? How would be the distribution of this variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider a generalized ordered logistic regression. This relaxes the parallel slopes assumption and can be easier to interpret than  multinomial logistic regression.

Here's a link to an article by Richard Williams on the topic:

https://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/gologit2/UnderStandingGologit2016.pdf